# Can you block an attack that an ally is trying to make?

Tags: dnd-5e, poison, dragonborn, defense, breath-weapon

My dragonborn friend keeps (accidentally) downing half the party with his poisonous [Breath Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/dragonborn#DragonbornTraits).

I'd like to know if I can block his poisonous breath so that the party doesn't go down anymore due to friendly fire, by using a shield or some kind of action to prevent him from doing this again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Not a bad first question, but we do need some clarification. Is this pvp, or is he hitting his own party? Has anyone complained about this (you, him, party members, DM)?

Comment: Wait, your friend is *already* consistently attacking his own party? Is player-vs-player combat part of the expectations for your game?

Comment: Is this intentional, or is the rest of the party just getting caught in the area because the dragonborn isn’t being careful? I think we need more of the story to understand and help the problem.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: How does the dragonborn manage to herd everyone in such a small place, roll maximum damage, and make everyone fail their save? I do not see any other way for him to keep _killing_ the party.

Comment: He's hitting the party accidentally, But its consistently happening. I may have exaggerated by saying "he keeps killing the entire party" but its pretty bad when half of us are downed by him. We've asked him to be more careful but im really looking for a way to prevent this type of thing happening again.

Comment: What is your level and class?  It would be helpful to know what abilities are at your disposal.

Comment: @PinkSweetener level one paladin

Comment: Another question, are you using a grid or a looser approach? If using a grid, he should know precisely who will be hit. And the answer to your problem becomes simpler. If using one of the looser approaches,  giving info on how you deal with area effect like those would be useful.

Comment: @3C273 grid, not sure how he manages to down most of us using a grid but he claims to be accidentally doing it. he's new to the game so i believe him, but i don't want to have the party downed in future.

Comment: @Idon'texist I'm curious, doesn't the GM warn him that he will be doing frendly fire? Or call out to the target to warn them that they will be in the line of fire? Or do the other players pay attention to where he is throwing his breath? Not throwing blame, but this is the way I'd tackle the issue if I was in your place (Will get down to write an answer when I can)

Comment: @3C273 GM told nobody, I wasnt really paying attention until i was told by GM that he hit most of us and half the party was just downed like that. This was during a fight with a group of skeletons. He tried to damage some of the skeletons but since most of us chose to melee attack we were in the line of fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure a shield would work. There is a spell that might: [*protection from poison*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-poison).

> You touch a creature. If it is poisoned, you neutralize the poison. If more than one poison afflicts the target, you neutralize one poison that you know is present, or you neutralize one at random.
>
> For the duration, the target has an advantage on saving throws against being poisoned, and it has resistance to poison damage.

If it is accidental, then he should just not use it in range of the party. If he is doing it on purpose... that's when unlawful and evil alignments come in handy.

Dwarves have "Dwarven Resilience", Stout Halflings have "Stout Resilience", and Monks have "Purity of Body" to protect against poison.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: It is a sad state of affairs when the PCs need to prepare to protect themselves from their ally as much as they need to prepare to protect themselves from their enemies,